# ipv6 Aggregatable global unicast addresses

Tags: ip, ipv6, rfc, route-summarization

Studying IPv6 addressing I haven't understood IPv6 aggregable global unicast addresses, I mean on  [RFC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291) there is a generic scheme:

```
|         n bits         |   m bits  |       128-n-m bits         |
+------------------------+-----------+----------------------------+
| global routing prefix  | subnet ID |       interface ID         |
+------------------------+-----------+----------------------------+
```

But looking for formats used I see in my book(Halsall) the format used is this:

```
|  3  | 5  |  8   |    32          |       16      |          64                    |
+-----+----+------+----------------+---------------+--------------------------------+
| 010 | reg| TLA  |  NLA           |  SLA          |  interface ID                  |
+-----+----+------+----------------+---------------+--------------------------------+
```

and in the web, for example on the [microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee494848.aspx), the format used is this:

```
|  3  |     13    |     8    |       24      |    16     |      64                  |
+-----+----+------+----------+---------------+-----------+--------------------------+
| 001 |    TLA    | reserved |    NLA        |    SLA    |        interface ID      |
+-----+----+------+----------+---------------+-----------+--------------------------+
```

My questions are:

- why is there more than one format of aggregatable global unicast addresses?
- Are there other formats or these 2 are the only 2 defined?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### TLA/NLA structure for IPv6 addresses

The TLA/NLA allocation structure has been deprecated in [RFC 3587](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=3587), August 2003:

> 2.  TLA/NLA Made Historic
>
> The TLA/NLA scheme has been replaced by a coordinated allocation policy 
>       defined by the Regional Internet Registries (RIRs) [[IPV6RIR](http://www.ripe.net/ripe/docs/ipv6policy.html)].
>
> Part of the motivation for obsoleting the TLA/NLA structure is
>       technical; for instance, there is concern that TLA/NLA is not the
>       technically best approach at this stage of the deployment of IPv6.
>       Moreover, the allocation of IPv6 addresses is related to policy and
>       to the stewardship of the IP address space and routing table size,
>       which the RIRs have been managing for IPv4.  It is likely that the
>       RIRs' policy will evolve as IPv6 deployment proceeds.
>
> The IETF has provided technical input to the RIRs (for example,
>       [[RFC3177](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=3177)]), which the RIRs have taken into account when defining
>       their address allocation policy.
>
> [RFC 2374](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=2374) was the definition of addresses for Format Prefix 001
>       (2000::/3) which is formally made historic by this document.  Even
>       though currently only 2000::/3 is being delegated by the IANA,
>       implementations should not make any assumptions about 2000::/3 being
>       special.  In the future, the IANA might be directed to delegate
>       currently unassigned portions of the IPv6 address space for the
>       purpose of Global Unicast as well.
>
> The Subnet Local Aggregator (SLA) field in [RFC 2374](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=2374) remains in
>       function but with a different name in [[ARCH](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=3513)].  Its new name is
>       "subnet ID".

As can be seen in the last paragraph, the **SLA** has survived from the three, now being called **subnet ID**.

I think they should have obsoleted [RFC 2450](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=2450) together with [RFC 2374](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=2374) in [RFC 3587](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=3587). It does not make sense anymore, but it was only informational anyway.

#### Global Unicast prefixes

Your book is certainly wrong on the prefix. A bit prefix of `010` would mean the address space of `4000::/3`, which *is* indeed Global Unicast as to [RFC 4291](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=4291), but does not identify the *whole* Global Unicast range, and is not even the one currently assigned by IANA, which is only `2000::/3` (i.e. address bits starting with `001`).

In fact, almost all addresses before `fc00::/128` (which starts the Unique Local Unicast address range) are Global Unicast, with the exceptions of the unspecified address `::` and the loopback address `::1`. There are some special ranges starting with the bits `000`, like `::ffff:0:0/96` (IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses) or `64:ff9b::/96` (for IPv4/IPv6 address translation, see [RFC 6052](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=6052)). They allow Interface Identifiers with less than 64 bits. But all addresses starting with `001` have a 64 bit Interface Identifier (see [RFC 4291, section 2.5.4](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=4291#section-2.5.4), right from where you cited).

As I can see, the definition of the address structure from [RFC 4291](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=4291) is the most current one. There are three RFCs updating 4291 ([RFC 5952](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=5952), [RFC 6052](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=6052), [RFC 7136](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=7136)), but none of them changes this structure.

Please note that the [[IPV6RIR](http://www.ripe.net/ripe/docs/ipv6policy.html)] reference points to the IPv6 registry policies, currently being [ripe-589](http://www.ripe.net/ripe/docs/ripe-589) which is "developed through joint discussions among the APNIC, ARIN and RIPE communities."

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 2450 - Proposed TLA and NLA Assignment Rules](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2450)

Microsoft's is in line with the proposed IETF RFC 2450.  Since it's still proposed, it isn't finalized, but it's the likely end format.